# Android read_external_storage permission request question

Tags: android

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList[] getFileList() {
        ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[2];
        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> infor = new ArrayList<>();

        String sdcard_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

        Log.d("TAG", sdcard_path);
        File target_dic = new File(sdcard_path);
        File[] target_files = target_dic.listFiles();

        if(target_files.length != 0) {
            for(File file : target_files) {
                files.add(file.getName());
                infor.add(file.length() + "B");
            }
        }

        arr[0] = files;
        arr[1] = infor;

        return arr;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    private void setRecyclerView(ArrayList<String> list, ArrayList<String> list2) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list, list2, getDeviceWidth(), MainActivity.this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }

            @Override
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        initMenuButton();
        setupPermission();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    private void setupPermission() {
        int chk = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (chk == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
                return;
            }
        }

        if(chk == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ArrayList[] arr = getFileList();
            setRecyclerView(arr[0], arr[1]);
        }

        return;
    }

    @Override
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("TAG", "권한결과 체크함수 호출됨.");

        if(requestCode == 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ArrayList[] arr = getFileList();
            setRecyclerView(arr[0], arr[1]);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "권한을 설정해주세요.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.moonsung.todaymusic">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In order, these are Java files and manifest files.
The app I'm making is a song streaming app, and I was trying to bring files and folders in sdcard first. However, the .listFiles() function kept returning null, and I realized that this was a permission issue and wrote a function that requests permission called setupPermission. However, after the permission request window pops up at the beginning, it works fine after allowing it, but running the app first, granting permission, and then running it from the second time does not work well. If I already have the read_external_storage permission, I just load the list, but it doesn't work. In the emulator, only the files that existed when permission was granted in the beginning were loaded well, and the files added afterwards could not be retrieved, and on mobile phones, an error that returns null from listFiles() still occurs. How can I fix this?

Comment: An Android 10 device?

Comment: Please remove most of your code. Why should you bother us with a recyclerview, an adapter or the color of your buttons?

Comment: I'm really sorry. Unnecessary Java code and xml code have been removed.

Comment: Summarizing the problem again this, the first time you start the app and allow file read permission, the file lists appear normally, but when you start the app after that, the list of files does not appear normally and the .listFiles() function returns null.

Comment: After that, even if I run the app, the permission does not disappear and is applied as it is, so the last if(chk == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {part of the setupPermission function runs normally, but the file list is not loaded.

Comment: `if(target_files.length != 0)` Where is the code for checking if listFiles() returned null as you said? `if(target_files==null) return;`

Comment: Files[] target_files = target_dic.listFiles(); In this part, the target_files value will be null (listFiles() returns null.) So in the if (target_files.length! = 0) part, I get an error saying that the null value has no length.

Comment: Yes i thought so. So why dont you add `if(target_files==null) return;` was my question. Display a toast too to inform the user.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the good point. Then I am wondering if I can see why listFiles() function returns null. I can detect null values ​​and notify users, but I don't want to return null values. The directory path also points to the sdcard correctly and all the permissions are given, but I am wondering why it keeps returning null.

Comment: You did not react on my first comment. Further i understood that it not returned null the first time you run the app. Very strange.

Comment: `The directory path also points to the sdcard correctly` ? What do you have in mind? It points to external storage. But not to a removable micro sd card.